# Image reconstruction with PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, image-processing

I am reading the following paper, which describes a technique based on image reconstruction with PCA:

> Luis Malagón-Borja, Olac Fuentes, Object detection using image reconstruction with PCA, Image and Vision Computing, Volume 27, Issue 1, 2009, Pages 2-9, ISSN 0262-8856, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.imavis.2007.03.004.

The relevant step is where the reconstruction error is described. Given an image $u$, its projection $p$ onto a set of principal components $P$ (computed from an image set) is given by $p = P(u - \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the mean of the image $u$ as a vector. Thus, its reconstruction $u'$ is given by:
$$u' = P^{T}p + \mu = P^{T}P(u - \mu) + \mu.$$
What I am having trouble understanding is the following. If P is the set of principal components obtained via PCA, it is also an orthogonal matrix. If P is orthogonal, wouldn't it be the case that  $P^{T}P=PP^{T}=I$, and consequently $u' = u$? I am sure that I am interpreting something wrong, since this would imply a perfect reconstruction no matter what dataset P was computed from.

Comment: P is a matrix and not a set. Reconstruction should be a linear combination of principal components. The whole point is to reduce / compress information so P wont be a square matrix.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, calling P a set was a mistake. Regarding P not being a square matrix, in this case the objective is not compression, so I believe it could be square. The idea is to reconstruct the image from principal components computed from a set of images, so that the reconstruction error can be used to determine how likely this image is to belong to this set.

Comment: PCA is a method for dimensionality reduction. There would be not be much of a point in doing a principal component analysis if you stored all the principal components without any alteration / dropping the less principal ones.

Comment: This is a classification rather than a compression application. The point in this case is that the principal components were not computed from the image you are trying to reconstruct, but from a set of images of some kind of object. The reconstruction will hardly be accurate, but the error can be used to estimate if the image you are trying to reconstruct belongs to this class of objects. The premise is that principal components from another class would yield higher reconstruction error.

Comment: Classification is compression.

Comment: Fair enough. My point is just that in this application there is a point to reconstructing without dropping principal components.

Answer (score 1):

$P$ is the matrix whose columns are the first $k$ eigenvectors of $C$.

Hence, $P \in \mathbb{R}^{ rc \times k}$

Hence $P^TP =I_k \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$.

Also $PP^T \in \mathbb{R}^{rc \times rc}$, if $k < rc$, this is a singular matrix.

Remark: I do think the authors are confused about $PP^T$ and $P^TP$.

The matrix multiplication $p=P(u - \mu)$ does not makes sense as the size is not compatible.

Comment: Although I can't access the paper this is basically a correct description of PCA and should be accepted.

Comment: Yes, I just think they are confusing $P$ and $P^T$. The notation is swapped consistently throughout the whole paper.

Comment: That sounds bad. You would think the reviewers should find such a trivial mistake.. But well I suppose it is hard finding good reviewers these days.